# html5 audio codec

Tags: xhtml, audio, html, html5-audio

I'm using html5 audio tag and can't seem to find what to specify for the codec for both mp3 and wav.

I know ogg is:

```
<audio>
<source type='audio/ogg; codec="vorbis"' />
</audio>
```

Anyone know what I would write for mp3 and wav?

Answer (score 6):

The best reference for `<source type="">` keywords is *not* the [IANA media types registry](https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml), as you might think, but [developer.mozilla.org's "Media formats for HTML audio and video" article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Supported_media_formats), which documents what browsers (not just Firefox) actually implement, instead of what the RFCs say is supposed to happen.  (For instance, there is no official MIME type for .WAV files.)

For the audio container formats you mention, these are my recommended `source` tags:

- Ogg: `<source type="audio/ogg">`
- MP3: `<source type="audio/mpeg">`
- WAV: `<source type="audio/wav">` (annoyingly, `audio/wave` is simultaneously "preferred" and "does not work with Chrome", thanks ever so much Google).

I recommend you do *not* specify exactly which codec you are using, because this embeds details that could change into the HTML.  The browser will figure it out.  (Really, this entire mess should have been handled using a generic URL directly on the `audio` tag, and an `Accept:` header on the HTTP request, but nobody listens to me.)

Comment: If you don't specify a codec then the browser opens the file a little bit to see if it can play it. That is the benefit of adding the codec values. I would like to try and figure this out.

Comment: @keith, I'm not sure this is correct.  I know that Firefox is smart enough to skip files based on MIME type alone.

Comment: @Brad Pedantically, there is no official media type registration for WAVs, so _nothing_ is correct.  According to the documentation I'm reading, `audio/wave` is "preferred" but also "does not work with Chrome," which sounds like some people need to be locked in a room till they come to an agreement.  And submit an official media type registration.

Comment: @zwol Yeah, standards would be nice.  :-)  I'm just happy WAV files work at all!  I used to have to decode them in JavaScript and bang them out via the Web Audio API ScriptProcessorNode.

Answer (score 1):

what browser are you using for playing the mp3 file? not all browsers support playing of mp3 trough the audio tag yet. see: http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/html5-audio-radio-player/
I suggest making a script that chooses the audio type according to the browser type. That way the user always has playing music.

Comment: That's the point of providing multiple sources and telling the browser which codec they are. The browser picks for itself the one it supports. You don't need to do that for it.

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax for Vorbis in Ogg is close to correct, just be sure to use `codecs`, plural:

```
audio/ogg; codecs=vorbis
```

Browsers do not support PCM and MP3 in Ogg.  But, PCM is supported in WAV, and for that you would use:

```
audio/wav; codecs=1
```

(For the constant `1`, `WAVE_FORMAT_PCM`, see the Appendix A of [RFC2361](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2361).)

For normal MPEG Layer 3 audio, there is no real container other than the bitstream itself, so just use:

```
audio/mpeg
```

Finally, as others have mentioned, you don't need to explicitly specify the codecs.  Specifying the file type is enough.  But, if you do already know the codecs it helps to specify, for efficient loading and less probing.